# ASP .Net Core: how to config auto mapper profile for different source and destination

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, automapper

let me say what i have:

CarDto Class code  is like below:

```
namespace MyNamespace.AppService.Contract.Cars;

public class CarDto : BaseDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
}
```

Car Model Class code is like below:

```
namespace MyNamespace.Model.Cars;

public class Car : BaseModel<Car>
{
    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    private string _name;
    private string? _description;
    
    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set
        {
            if (value.Length is < 2 or > 40)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            _name = value;
        }
    }

    public string? Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            if (value is { Length: > 800 })
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The length of the Description property cannot be greater than 800 characters.");
            _description = value;
        }
    }

    protected override Car Edit(Car model)
    {
        Name = model.Name;
        Description = model.Description;
        return this;
    }
}
```

and we Use AutoMapper to map this to class, so my CarProfile that have automapper configuration is like below code:

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyRBV.AppService.Contract.Cars;
using MyRBV.Model.Cars;

namespace MyNamespace.AppService.Profiles;

public class CarProfile: Profile
{
    public CarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CarDto, Car>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
           
             .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

when i run below Unittest Code:

```
 [Fact]
    public async Task Add_CheckInvalidCarDescription_ThrowValidationException()
    {
        var car = new CarDto
        {
            Name = new string('c',20),
            Description = new string('c', 802)
        };
        var action = new Func<Task<CarDto>>(() => _service.Add(car));
        await action.Should().ThrowAsync<ArgumentOutOfRangeException>();
    }
```

i get below error:

```
found <AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException>: "
"AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException with message "Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
CarDto -> Car
MyRBV.AppService.Contract.Cars.CarDto -> MyRBV.Model.Cars.Car

Type Map configuration:
CarDto -> Car
MyRBV.AppService.Contract.Cars.CarDto -> MyRBV.Model.Cars.Car

Destination Member:
Description
"
```

i want ArgumentOutOfRangeException error be triggered in my Car Model, but i have this problem,

i did some search i changed my CarProfile to below code and error solved and my test passed.

here is ne CarProfile that solved the problem

```
using AutoMapper;
using MyRBV.AppService.Contract.Cars;
using MyRBV.Model.Cars;

namespace MyNamespace.AppService.Profiles;

public class CarProfile: Profile
{
    public CarProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<CarDto, Car>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
            //.ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Condition(src => (src.Description?.Length<=800)))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Description))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Description, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .AfterMap((src, dest) => {
                if (src.Description?.Length > 800)
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Description");
            })
             .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

but i want `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in CarMdel Class throw when i give Description with more than 800 char lenght to my `Add_CheckInvalidCarDescription_ThrowValidationException()` test function for more clear code,

Comment: Does the AutoMapper exception have the `ArgumentOutOfRangeException ` as an inner exception?

Comment: @stuartd yes, its solved my problem but i think its not good to have exception in automapper